# Application open within application

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have implemented deeplinking in my application that open my app (if available) but my app opens within other application. I want it should open out of the other app.

Here is my code for deeplinking.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
    android:host="controller"
    android:path="/productDetail"
    android:scheme="lalaland" />
</intent-filter>
```

Example: If i hit a url in slack it opens my app ( lalaland ) with in slack. [image: here is an image that show my is opened in slack (other app) but other app is running named as lalaland]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are at the mercy of the application that the user executed the deep-link from.

I'm afraid there is no solution for this. For example, Facebook messenger butchers deep-links rendering them unusable in many cases, same with the Samsung messaging app.

What you see here is Slack hijacking the deep-link and forcing it to open within its own app.

Comment: Many apps like facebook, tweeter, quora and slack too is opening the app correctly (out of the app)

Comment: Like i said, its dependant on the app that the user executes the deep-link from. As you have just stated yourself, the implementation has not changed only the executing app.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this issue the other day and found the following solution from the Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element see section about `android:launchMode`)

After changing my `android:launchMode` from `singleTop` to `singleInstance` on the `<activity>`-element, the universal-/deep-links now moves the users into my app, instead of opening an instance of the app within the Slack app.

`singleTop` allows multiple instances of the same activity to run, unlike `singleInstance` which only allows one instance.

This is an old question, but I hope this helps someone else who stumbles upon it, years later (like me)!